# Solve $(1+x)^2=A\sqrt{1+Cx}$ for $x$.

Tags: algebraic-equations

$x>0$, $A>0$ and $C>1$.

I am trying to come up with a closed form expression for $x$, even if it is an approximation.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried squaring both sides? I know it may add more solutions but doing something generally generates more interest in your question

Comment: I've tried to solve the quartic equation and it is doable, if we can solve the following:
$$
z  (z + 1)(z +2) = AC^2 \ / \ (C-1)^{3/2}
$$
At least one solution $z$ is needed, although getting all solutions makes later calculations easier. In further calculations
$$
z\cdot A{(C-1)^{1/2}}
$$
is used. Would this be any help?
$\\ $
I used the algorithm from [http://www.sosmath.com/algebra/factor/fac12/fac12.html ], see also [http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/faq.cubic.equations.html ].

Comment: @eudes
or
$$
w^3 - w = AC^2 \ / \ (C-1)^{3/2}, \quad w = z+1
$$

Comment: @eudes I looked at the algorithms but I don't know what can be done about the cubic equation, since I can't say anything about $A$ or $C$ other than what I posted in the question. I think I will resort to numerical approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Squaring your equation and expanding we get
$$x^4+4x^3+6x^2+4x-A^2Cx+1-A^2=0$$
It is a polynomial of degree four.I think you will need a numerical method, if values for the parameters are given.

Comment: You left out one term.

Comment: Yes, thank you, $$A^2$$ was missing

Answer (score 2):

Square both sides and you get a quartic equation for $x$.  Quartics do have closed-form solutions, but they are not pretty.

If you want an approximation, you should tell us what parameters can be considered as "small" or "large".

Answer (score 1):

Numerically you can solve it using iterative process. Take initial approximation for your root, let's say $x_0=1$ and calculate the next approximation using this formula:  $$x_k=\sqrt{A\sqrt{1+Cx_{k-1}}}-1$$
Stop the process when $|x_k-x_{k-1}|$ is small enough for your application.